# How to disable/remove click event on asp.net tree view parent nodes?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, treeview

I have a tree view in my aspx page with one level of child nodes. I want to disable the click on just the parent node of the tree view and its child nodes still be clickable. How can I disable click event just on the parent node. Is there a way to do this in c# or in java script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

check out the below link

[remove Hyperlink from ASP.NET TreeView Nodes Control Nodes](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/112388/How-to-remove-Hyperlink-from-ASP-NET-TreeView-Node)

hope this helps you.

Comment: Please read [Are answers that just contain links elsewhere really “good answers”?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231)